# Elasticsearch: id vs other field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

I created an index in ES, with several textfields. One of them I named "id" just for sake of an identifier. Is there something special about "id" field in ES?

I observe that a query like(I am using elastic4s API):

```
search("items").query("id", "101")
```

...works fine.But very same query for another field doesn't work at all:

```
search("items").query("name", "Chair")
```

Comment: What are the types of your fields?

Comment: I have used TextField for both 'id' and 'name'.